# Best alternative for FOUND_ROWS() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pdo

I was searching on NET for alternative to MySQL FOUND_ROWS(), how to get all rows when using limit and WHERE. I need this for pagination.

I found a few different approach, but I don't have much experience (I migrate to PostgreSQL a week ago) which approach will give the best performance?

```
SELECT stuff, count(*) OVER() AS total_count
FROM table
WHERE condition
ORDER BY stuff OFFSET 40 LIMIT 20

BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM mytable OFFSET X LIMIT Y;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable;
END;

BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT id, username, title, date FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20;
SELECT count(id, username, title, date) AS total FROM posts;
END;

select * into tmp_tbl from tbl where [limitations];
select * from tmp_tbl offset 10 limit 10;
select count(*) from tmp_tbl;
drop table tmp_tbl;
```

If there is another approach not described yet and will get the best performance, please let me know.

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.3.4 and PDO for PHP.

Comment: The first variant is the best. There may be various ways to improve performance, depending on all the circumstances. Like a partial index or a materialized view with a gap-less serial number.